# VBA и SQL. Разделение таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, vba

Имеется таблица с полями a, b, c, d. Тип полей заранее неизвестен. Необходимо создать новую таблицу и скопировать туда поле с и соединить его с полем с в исходной таблице.

Среда программирования: MS VBA 7.1

СУБД: Microsoft Access 2013

Comment: Необходимо - создайте. В чем вопрос не ясно.

Comment: Вопрос как раз в том, как это сделать? Я не знаю, как именно создать поле "такого же типа данных", как с

Comment: Укажите что за СУБД.

Comment: СУБД: Microsoft Access 2013 - добавил в шапку

Comment: intFieldType = CurrentDb.TableDefs("table").Fields(num).Type

Comment: сильно неуверен, но можно попробовать что-то вроде select c into new_table from old_table Не знаюю создаст ли аксес автоматом новую таблицу, но судя по http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892273/create-a-table-from-a-query-in-access-vba должен

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, оба ваших ответа оказались правильными!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще сделать так:

```
SELECT c Into new_table from Old_table;
```

Таблица создается на лету.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ от пользователя [Nikola Tesla](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/203198/nikola-tesla)

Чтобы узнать тип данных для столбца `N` таблицы `M` нужно обратиться к: `CurrentDB.Tabledefs("M").Fields(N).Type` - вернёт число типа integer - числовой код типа данных столбца `N` таблицы `M`.

Для копирования столбца `C` из таблицы `A` в таблицу `B`, необходимо выполнить запрос:

```
SELECT C INTO B FROM A
```